# How to link .hpp file using make

Tags: c++, makefile, linker, linker-errors

**This is my makefile:**

```
all: prog

output: run.o ruin.o interm.o
    g++ run.o ruin.o interm.o -o output

run.o: run.cpp
    g++ -c run.cpp
ruin.o: ruin.hpp
    g++ -c ruin.hpp
interm.o: interm.cpp
    g++ -c interm.cpp

OBJECTS = run.o ruin.o interm.o
INC = -I include
LIBS = -L lib -lsfml-system -lsfml-window -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-audio
CC = g++ 

prog:   $(OBJECTS)
        $(CC) $(OBJECTS) $(INC) $(LIBS) -o prog


clean:
    rm *.o
```

**This is the error I get on compiling:**

```
make: *** No rule to make target `ruin.o', needed by `prog'.  Stop.
```

Comment: You don't compile and link header files separately. You just include the file in one or more cpp files as needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @Retired Ninja in the comment, you'll need to include the file in one or more cpp files, for example the `Makefile` could be updated like that

```
CC = g++
CFLAGS = -I include
LIBS = -L lib -lsfml-system -lsfml-window -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-audio
OBJECTS = run.o ruin.o interm.o

all: prog

run.o: run.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c run.cpp
ruin.o: ruin.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c ruin.cpp
interm.o: interm.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c interm.cpp

prog: $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(OBJECTS) $(LIBS) -o prog

clean:
    rm -f *.o prog
```

Comment: there are some errors in your makefile `*** missing separator.  Stop.`

Comment: you need to convert spaces to tabs